# Calculate total jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a question I can correctly added to the total price take into account 3 types of goods. 
Each has input with the number of goods. 
When mutations both count the total price becomes irregular. 
How can I do to correct total price becomes? [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zk3gfb4w/) 
Sorry for my English, I hope you will realize what I mean

```
$('.checkbox').change(function () {
    var item = $(this).parent();
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        addPrice(item);
    } else {
        removePrice(item);
    }
});

function addPrice(item) {
    var price = $(item).find('.price').text().replace('.', '');
    var totalPrice = $('.total-price').text().replace('.', '');
    var addToPrice = (parseFloat(totalPrice) + parseFloat(price)).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");

    $('.total-price').text(addToPrice);
}

function removePrice(item) {
    var price = $(item).find('.price').text().replace('.', '');
    var totalPrice = $('.total-price').text().replace('.', '');
    var addToPrice = (parseFloat(totalPrice) - parseFloat(price)).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");

    $('.total-price').text(addToPrice);
}

$(document).on('input', '.quniti',function(){
    var item = $(this).parent();

    var quniti = $(item).find('.col').val();
    var totalPriceOld = $('.total-price').text();

    var addPrice = (parseFloat(quniti) * parseFloat($(this).val() || 0));
    var addTotalPrice = (parseFloat(totalPriceOld) + parseFloat(addPrice));

    $(item).find('label').text(addPrice.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "."));

    if ($(item).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked') ) {
        $('.total-price').text( addTotalPrice.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".") );
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do you replace stuff? Just use toFixed(3) on the amounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this structure

```
$('.checkbox').change(function () {
   recount();
});

function recount() {
    var sum=0;
  $('.price').each(function(){
        if ($(this).parent().find('.checkbox').is(":checked")){
    sum += parseFloat($(this).text()); 
    $('.total-price').text(sum);
        }
});
}

$(document).on('input', '.quniti',function(){
    var item = $(this).parent();

    var quniti = $(item).find('.col').val();
    var addPrice = (parseFloat(quniti) * parseFloat($(this).val() || 0));

    $(item).find('label').text(addPrice.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "."));
    recount();
    });
```

Working example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zk3gfb4w/11/).

Answer (score 0):

it's my first time here, so pardon me if there are any mistakes

i think you need to make the flow more simple, here is the HTML

```
<div class="tovar">
    <input type="checkbox" id="span1" class="checkbox">
    <label for="span1" class="price">1.360</label>
    <input type="text" class="quniti">
</div>
<div class="tovar">
    <input type="checkbox" id="span2" class="checkbox">
    <label for="span2" class="price">1.270</label>
    <input type="text" class="quniti">
</div>
<div class="tovar">
    <input type="checkbox" id="span3" class="checkbox">
    <label for="span3" class="price">1.470</label>
    <input type="text" class="quniti">
</div>
<div class="total-price">35</div>
```

And here is the js

```
$('.checkbox').change(function () {
    var item = $(this).parent();
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        addPrice(item);
    } else {
        removePrice(item);
    }
});

function addPrice(item) {
    var price = parseFloat($(item).find('.price').text());
    var quniti = parseFloat($(item).find('.quniti').val() || 0);
    var totalPrice = parseFloat($('.total-price').text());
    var newPrice = totalPrice + quniti * price;

    $('.total-price').text(newPrice);
}

function removePrice(item) {
    var price = parseFloat($(item).find('.price').text());
    var quniti = parseFloat($(item).find('.quniti').val() || 0);
    var totalPrice = parseFloat($('.total-price').text());
    var newPrice = totalPrice - quniti * price;

    $('.total-price').text(newPrice);
}
```

sample: http://jsfiddle.net/zk3gfb4w/12/